# Display data from several fields in MySQL-table with specific id

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code (SQL-query tested in phpMyAdmin and seems to work) that fetch data from selected columns:

```
                $ids = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : array();
                if (is_array($ids)) $ids = implode(',', $ids);

                if (!empty($ids)) {

                    $sql = "SELECT upload, upload2, upload3, upload4, upload5 FROM wp_site_table WHERE cid IN($ids) ORDER BY FIELD(cid, $ids)";

                    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                    foreach( $results as $result ) { ... } }
```

The problem I have is that I want to output all fields from selected cid.

This code will only display the first cid result.

```
echo $result->upload;
```

Let's say $ids contain cid 1, 4 and 7 I'd like to output upload, upload2, upload4, upload5 from all those specific rows. How? Use an array in some way?

kind regards
Johan

Comment: If the query works in phpMyAdmin, this seems to be an issue with `$wpdb->get_results()` not returning all the results.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Barmar. If i print_r($results); It prints the array and all fields is visible there.

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [upload] => [upload2] => 1068 [upload3] => 1069 [upload4] => 1070 [upload5] => 1071 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [upload] => [upload2] => 1072 [upload3] => 1073 [upload4] => 1074 [upload5] => 1075 ) )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to echo all the fields, just do it:

```
echo $result->upload . '<br>' . $result->upload2 . '<br>' . $result->upload3 .
    '<br>' . $result->upload4 . '<br>' . $result->upload5;
```

You should perhaps consider redesigning your database so you don't have repeated fields in each row. It would be better to have another table where each `upload` is in a row of its own, so there's no hard-coded limit on the number of these values. Then you can use a `JOIN` query to get all the `uploads`, and they'll be in an array.

Comment: Thanks again for reply. :) your code will display results from the first cid (let's say cid = 5) but let's say I also have cid = 6, cid = 8 in the query... They are not displayed. is there a way to make this work with what I have today, since there would be alot of work to rebuild everything.

Comment: The `foreach` loop should go through all the rows of results.

Comment: `print_r($results)` shows that all the rows are in there. Is this code inside the `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

With '$wpdb->get_results' output defaults to OBJECT type. Try using pre defined constant : ARRAY_A , it will result the output as an associative array.

```
$sql = "SELECT upload, upload2, upload3, upload4, upload5 FROM wp_site_table WHERE cid  IN($ids) ORDER BY FIELD(cid, $ids)";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A) or die(mysql_error());
```

To access, simply use :

```
foreach( $results as $result ){
  echo $result['upload'];
}
```

Comment: I think you're maybe right here. The problem I have is when I add foreach( $results as $result ) { echo $result->upload; }

I get following notice: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object... on $result->upload; Any thought on that? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes, because the returned type is now an array, not an object. So you can now access using : foreach( $results as $result ){
  echo $result['upload'];
}   I have updated my answer too. Hope this helps.